# How to ignore specific attributes in Laravel's ConvertEmptyStringsToNull?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel includes a global middleware called [`ConvertEmptyStringsToNull`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f578bbce25843492fc996ac96797e0395e16cf2e/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php)

With the middleware, a request to `GET /somewhere?something` results in `something === null`

Without the middleware, this request results in `something === ''`

**How can I disable it for specific attribute names?**

For example, if you look at another globally included middleware [`TrimStrings`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a67aeeb68bad370efa91eaa9825db9abdae7c72c/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php) you'll notice it contains an `except` property.

```
/**
 * The attributes that should not be trimmed.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    //
];
```

In this case, the middleware is applied to every attribute except those named here. I tried extending `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` in the same manner, but it doesn't work. I feel like I'm missing something basic.

I would like to be able to add exceptions for this middleware so that I get the empty string only for specific attribute names. e.g. except `exemption`

- `GET /somewhere?something` : `something === null`
- `GET /somewhere?exemption` : `exemption === ''`
- `GET /somewhere?everything` : `everything === null`

Comment: I think you can use $except = ['/somewhere'];

Comment: @Vishal nope, but thanks. Anyway, that would imply ignoring the whole route, to whereas my question was for exempting single attributes from all routes - as it works in `TrimStrings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can extend `TransformsRequest` class as a custom middleware (because `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` also extends the same class) Then override the `transform()` method based on your need. A working example is the following

I will exclude request field 'abc' from being *set to null*. Sorry for *unclean* example, I used an array so incase I want to exclude more than one field.

```
//this is a middleware class I have removed `handle()` function leaving the default.
class NinjaAuther extends TransformsRequest
{

/**
 * Transform the given value.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function transform($key, $value)
{
        if(is_string($value) && !in_array($key,  ['abc'], true)) {
            $value = $value === '' ? null : $value;
        }

    return $value;
    }
}
```

Remove `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware from `$middleware` then include your own NinjaAuther middleware.

[image]
Then you are good to go! All request passes through your custom middleware! You can use it on middlewares for individual group as you need (in case you don't want to apply it on all requests)

> PS: I didn't really inspect cautiously the TransformRequest class but I think it should be safe, since anyway its being applied on all request in the default configuration inside Kernel.php